# parent node selection and child node selection in treeview in windows form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to select parent node and child node indiviudally into two seperate labels from treeview.
As per my current code i can select only one node either parent or child.
I have binded my treeview with DB columns and tables.
This is a windows forms application.
Below is my code to select current node.
Can any one please help me on this issue?

```
string s = treeView1.SelectedNode.ToString();
label1.Text = s.Substring(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

`TreeNode` has [`Parent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.parent.aspx) property, something like

```
string s = treeView1.SelectedNode.ToString();
label1.Text = s.Substring(10);
lable2.Text = treeView1.SelectedNode.Parent.ToString(); // parent
```

You have to check if it's not `null` and of `TreeNode` type normally and use recursion/loop to find topmost parent.

Comment: parent property doesnot work. I tried with that too. This statement returns null reference exception                           lable2.Text = treeView1.SelectedNode.Parent.ToString();

Comment: Oh yeah, it will `throw` for the most *parent* `TreeNode` (because it doesn't have parents). That's the fact, thanks for stating it!